# Show that the perimeter of an octagon is $8(\sqrt{2} -1)$

Tags: geometry, triangles

My question is as follows: The top of a table is made in the shape of a regular octagon by cutting the congruent isosceles triangles from the corners of a $1$ m square piece of wood. Show that the perimeter of the octagon is $8(\sqrt{2} -1)$ metres. 
Thanks

Comment: What have you attempted thus far in approaching this problem? ¶ One path to a solution is as follows: Each cut connects two points, each of which is some distance $x$ from the corner.  The length of the diagonal sides is thus $x\sqrt{2}$, whereas the length of the orthogonal sides is $1-2x$.  Equate those two and solve for $x$, then multiply by $8$ to get the perimeter.

Comment: Hey I have worked a different way out to get the question. Thanks @BrianTung

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is the octagon side on a side of the square after the cut then

$$\frac{1-x}{2}\sqrt{2}$$

is the other side of the octagon after the cut. Since we want a regular octagon we need:
$$
\frac{1-x}{2}\sqrt{2}=x \Rightarrow 1-x=\sqrt{2}x \Rightarrow x=\sqrt{2}-1
$$
and the perimeter is $8x=8(\sqrt{2}-1)$

Comment: Could I show you a way I did it on paper I don't know if it is right if you could I will leave my email :  cliveboy13@gmail.com @EmilioNovati

Comment: You can add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Might this be the graphical demonstration you had in mind?

The octagon in question is the inner hull of two concentric unit squares.  Each side is then evidently equal in length to the side of the little square at upper right, which in turn is equal in length to the excess of the diagonal of the unit square over its unit side (the two dashed segments).  Since the diagonal is $\sqrt{2}$, each side of the octagon is $\sqrt{2}-1$, and the perimeter is $8(\sqrt{2}-1)$.